# GET multiple values in a search request

Tags: attask

I am using the AtTask API to do some custom reporting and I would like to get back more than one of a particular parameter. For example, in the documentation it states:

> GET /attask/api/project/search?status=CUR

Is there a way to also get back APP, PLN, etc? i.e. I'd like to do one call and get back all projects with a particular set of statuses. I've tried:

```
status={CUR,APP,PLN}
status=CUR,APP,PLN
status=CUR&status=APP&status=PLN
```

So far none of those have returned the dataset. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last attempt is the closest. You just need to add `status_Mod=in`, so your statement would be:

```
GET /attask/api/project/search?status=CUR&status=APP&status=PLN&status_Mod=in
```