# How to Exclude Multiple Values from Search Results

Tags: attask

I want to get only a list of issues that a user is working on, as well as new issues that a user has been assigned to, and exclude any that have been closed or set to any status that doesn't mean new or currently working on.  I've tried

```
status=CLS&status_Mod=ne&status=WTR&status_Mod=ne
status=CLS,WTR&status_Mod=ne
status=CLS&status=WTR&status_Mod=ne
```

1 and 3 only work for filtering out the first status (CLS), and 2 didn't work at all.  How do I filter out both the CLS and WTR statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494081/get-multiple-values-in-a-search-request), which led me to figuring out the answer to my own question.  The last attempt in my question was the closest to what I needed, though my problem was that I needed to use `status_Mod=notin` instead of `status_Mod=ne`.

```
GET /attask/api/v4.0/optask/search?assignedToID=usersID&status=CLS&status=WTR&status_Mod=notin
```